# Retrieving information from callback functions in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, callback

(context) I'm creating a game which involves recreating a melody by selecting notes that python randomly generates from a list of audio files. I'm having trouble with retrieving and using information from callback functions in Tkinter. The relevant code is the following:

```
def PlayRandomNote(self):
    NoteIndex = random.randint(0, 6)
    Note = ListOfSamples[NoteIndex]
    self.PlayFile(Note)
    return Note

def Screen3(self,Melody):
    GuessedMelody = []
    self.PlayNote = ttk.Button(self.Main, text = "Play random note", command = self.PlayRandomNote)
    self.Question = Label(self.Main, text = "Was that the correct note?", bg = "black", fg = "white")
    self.Yes = ttk.Button (self.Main, text = "Yes", command = lambda: self.ThreeToFour(Melody, GuessedMelody))
    for Widget in self.Main.winfo_children():
        Widget.pack()
```

(question) I would like it so when the user presses the "yes" button, the last note which was played from pressing the "Play random note" button is added to my GuessedMelody list, and then this list is added as an argument to my ThreeToFour function (a function which transitions from the current screen to the next). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No instead of passing everything around you must use your object to hold the information. The below code is a rough guess of what you should aim for. Without the other code it is hard to tell. It may seem more efficient to pass, but it does not work and it is not necessary in python. For example you return the note in PlayRandomNote(self)... it does not have anywhere to go, so you must have a variable ready for it and assign it to that variable.

```py
def PlayRandomNote(self):
    NoteIndex = random.randint(0, 6)
    Note = ListOfSamples[NoteIndex]
    self.PlayFile(Note)
    self.curent_random_note

def Screen3(self):
    self.PlayNote = ttk.Button(self.Main, text = "Play random note", command = self.PlayRandomNote)
    self.Question = Label(self.Main, text = "Was that the correct note?", bg = "black", fg = "white")
    self.Yes = ttk.Button (self.Main, text = "Yes", command =  self.ThreeToFour)
    for Widget in self.Main.winfo_children():
        Widget.pack()
```